# Can conditional operator " ? : " be considered as an alternative to if-else statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Someone asked me this question in a workshop and about what are some alternative to the `if-else` statement in JavaScript except from `switch`. Is the conditional operator just a shorthand for `if-else`?

Comment: No, it is an expression not a statement. The two are not the same, even if you often can rewrite them to each other.

Comment: From docs - The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS is a "phrasal" programming language and strictly separates between *expressions* (values and operators) and *statements*. `?` is an operator and can be used within an expression:

```
a = x ? y : z
```

while `if` cannot, because it's a statement:

```
a = if (x)  ... // syntax error
```

On the other hand, every expression is also a statement, when used in an appropriate context:

```
 while (1)
    a = x ? y : z;
```

so it's fair to say that `?` is "broader" than `if` because it can be used in both contexts. Which of course doesn't mean it should (rather not).

If you're interested in other ways to express conditional logic, you can do that with boolean operators:

```
 a && do_something() // "if a do_something()"
 b || do_something() // "if not b do_something()"
```

although such uses are mostly considered bad style.

Comment: it's also worthy of note that `if-else` statement can contain other statements (e.g. `return`), whereas ternary can't.

Comment: Yes. And you, in a fact, **can** return an *expression*, while you **can not** return a *statement*.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat shorthand, but only in case of *returning / obtaining a value or object from two possible expressions*.

Examples:

```
// inside a function
if (condition) { return X; } else { return Y; }

// Functionally equivalent to
return condition ? X : Y;
```

```
var tmp;
if (condition) { tmp = GetFoo(123); } else { tmp = GetBar(456); }
DoSomething(tmp);

// Functionally equivalent to
DoSomething(condition ? GetFoo(123) : GetBar(456));
```

If there are no return values, there is still an equivalency but people might scream at you for doing this:

```
if (condition) { A(); } else { B(); }
// *shudder*
condition ? A() : B();
```

And the following are impossible or at least hard to change into `?:`:

```
if (condition) { A(); return true; } else { B(); return false; }
// Reason: code blocks contain multiple statements

if (condition) { tmp = GetFoo(123); }
// Reason: no "else"-block (or you need to construct/invent one)
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, except for the first "hard" example that you give. If you assign a variable to the return value of a function that has no `return` statement you get `undefined`, which is a legal value. So, `var d = condition ? A() : B();` is actually doable. `d` will be `undefined`, but the condition will be applied correctly. Or did I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: Thanks you're right, it is so uncommon (and ugly) that I forgot about it. You can even do it without an assigment; rephrased accordingly.